# draw qt widget bigger as the mouse hovers over it (overlapping of widgets)

Tags: qt, widget, hover, overlapping

I would like to create a simple effect with my qt gui, but i have no idea how to achieve this.

I have several widgets, that i implemented as subclasses of qwidget. These are part of another widget and live in a layout. When the mouse hovers over these widgets, i want them to appear bigger to highlight the selected one.

This is what i already tried:
Override the paint event, and simply paint it bigger. But then, the other widgets that also live in the same layout overpaint the oversized areas.

I also tried to call the paint function "by hand" from the parent window, to get control over the painting order. But that didnt help either.

I think there has to be a possibility achieving this effect this qt, but i simply dont know how.
Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think "painting it bigger" is a good idea, but did you try `raise()`ing the widget when you do that?

Comment: But i want to widget to really be bigger. Unfortunately `raise()` doesnt prevent the widget from being overpainted by the other widgets. If this helps: i want to have a similar effect to the auto hiding parts, like the solution explorer, of visual studio for example.

Comment: Then make it bigger with `resize()`, but that's probably going to mess  up your layout. You _might_ manage to make it work with spacers. I don't know, and I don't like stuff moving under the mouse. Changing colors/highlighting is ok though.

Comment: You are right, but my input device is not the mouse. I use the hand positions from the kinect skeleton tracking. And if i design control elements, that are big enough to fit the hands on the screen, my screen will be complete full with control elements. Thats why i want to scale them when the hand hovers over them.

Answer (score 0):

You could either:

- create your GUI inside a `QGraphicsView`, with `QGraphicsWidget`s and use `setScale` when the mouse enters or leave the widget, or
- use QML.